# Why is Bing map so pixelated on phonegap ? (compared to Gmaps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, bing-maps

I had to change fro Gmaps to Bing maps for perf reasons (Gmaps uses js intensively when BM uses silverlight which gives MUCH better results providing a native feeling). But to one issue fixed, I have a new one to solve ..

Why is bing map so pixelated on my app ? It's like if bing map was looking at the device-width resolution of 320px and not taking advantage of the sharpness of todays high res screens ? Am I missing something in Bing Maps configuration ? there is definitively an issue with dpi

I am using Bing Maps v7 with AJAX

Here is my meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`

Here is a comparision between BingM and Gmaps:
[image: GMaps]

[image: Bing Maps]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this issue is that the viewport information is not scaling the tiles. I've heard adding the following before loading the map works well:

Microsoft.Maps.Globals.defaultTileSize = 128;

Comment: One quick question, I couldn't find any reference to this Tile Size configuration in Microsoft official Doc ( I understand you're working in the team, great! ), even by searching through the search engine. Where was it ? Thanks :)

Comment: This is undocumented.

Comment: This kind of stuff should **really** be documented. On Ios and Android everything worked fine for me, but Edge on WP10 gave me horrible map quality.

Comment: The new Bing Maps V8 map control automatically detects the device resolution and uses high DPI map tiles as needed. This hack is no longer needed in the latest version of Bing Maps.

Comment: @rbrundritt There is still some issues on windows phone, on my Lumia 950 (windows 10) the tiles look really pixelated unless I use your 'hack' above. It's more likely yet another bug in windows edge though :/

Comment: The new Bing Maps V8 SDK has much better mobile support and automatically detects the screen resolution and uses high DPI map images when needed. I recommend upgrading your app to us that control. It is about 80% backwards compatible as well. Here are some resources: http://blogs.bing.com/maps/April-2016/Announcing-Bing-Maps-V8-control-for-the-Web You can also test this out by loading the new interactive SDK in your mobile browser.

Comment: @rbrundritt Thanks a bunch, I'll try it out soon